# When I try to upload artifacts to nexus using uploadArchives in gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, build.gradle, spring-cloud-contract

I have a spring boot project which using spring cloud contract.

I'm getting below error(with --stack trace) when I try to upload artifacts to nexus.

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Could not publish configuration 'archives'

Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not write to file '{projectpath}/build/poms/pom-default.xml'.

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner -> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner - Could not find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner:.' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultUnresolvedDependencyResult' to class 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedDependencyResult'

mates - any idea?

Comment: What's your gradle version and what's your scc plugin version?

Answer (score 1):

After multiple tries, it fixed by adding mavenBom

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
      mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-dependencies:${springCloudDependencies}"
    }
}
```